# How to prove that if $I+A$ and $I-A$ are nonsingular and $(I−A)(I+A)^{−1}$ is orthogonal then $A$ is skew symmetric?

Tags: matrices

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix with real elements so that $I+A$ and $I-A$ are nonsingular and $B=(I−A)(I+A)^{−1}$ is orthogonal. Is $A$ skew symmetric?

Comment: Did you mean $B=(I−A)(I+A)^{−1}$ or $B=(I−A)((I+A)^{−1})$ ?

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: until now i have that $xtAx=0$

Comment: I think you mean $$x^tAx=0$$

Comment: That's a good point. You can prove that $A$ is skew simmetric from that.

Comment: thank you so much! i got this now